# small description window on mouse hover on hyperlink

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

i have a sharepoint custom list and we have 2 columns in there URL and description. i have a list webpart which shows all the URLs from the sharepoint list. But when i mouse hover on the link i would like to show description for that link in a small window. Can anyone please help me implementing this using jquery. Jquery should be able to read the description from list. Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Have you tested "Jquery Tools overlay" with SharePoint 2010? I have. SharePoints' ridiculous ribbon/scroll handling messes the offset up, so the tooltips are not positioned correctly. It is very annoying and the remedy is to calculate the width/height of the ribbon thing and add them to the offset. All said and done, quite a bit of work, despite it being a standard plugin :-( I only got it 90% working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options for doing something like that :

1. In your list webpart, you show your URLs as your already do, but you also create divs for your description, you just hide them. Them, on hover, you show the information using jQuery (jQuery Tools Overlay or Tooltip or something like it will do)
2. If your description is big, or if you have a lot of elements in your list, you might want to use AJAX / SharePoint list web service to achieve this. It is a bit trickier but might be worth it.

You can find more details about this method [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/05/06/querying-sharepoint-list-items-using-jquery.aspx)

**EDIT:**

You could use jQuery to show your div very easily. Put the following markup in your code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(
      function () {
        $('#divDescription').show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $('#divDescription').hide();
      }
   );
  });
```

Read some tutorials on how to [get started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).

**EDIT 2:**
I'm assuming that you have markup like this :

```
<div>
  <a>Your First link</a>
  <div id="divDescription">Your First Description</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a>Your Second link</a>
  <div id="divDescription">Your SecondDescription</div>
</div>
...
```

Instead, you should do something like :

```
<div>
  <a>Your First link</a>
  <div class="description">Your First Description</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a>Your Second link</a>
  <div class="description">Your SecondDescription</div>
</div>
...
```

Notice how I use a class instead of an ID for the description div.

Then, in your javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).parent('div').find('.description').show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).parent('div').find('.description').hide();
      }
   );
  });
```

You need to understand what you are doing with jQuery in order to make this work. When you do `$("#divDescription").show();` you are selecting all the divs with the ID "divDescription" and showing them. Read more about the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) functions. I really recommend that you read up on javascript and jQuery to gain a better understanding of how it works. There are tons of tutorials online that will help you with that.

Comment: Hi, I have added div tag to decription and hiding it.Then in the content editor webpart Iam trying to use css to display this div on mouse hover.But I am not sure how to do this.
I added something like this on the content editor web part and on mouse hover my link is changing the color to red.Similarly i want to add a:hover {#divDescription{display:inline;}} Can we do something like this? Plesae help me.
<style>
a:hover{color: #ff0000 !important;}
a:hover {#divDescription{display:inline;}} 
</style>

Comment: Hi Hugo,

Thanks for your reply.ButI cannot see my webpart at all after I have added your code in content editor webpart. Am I missing anything here.

Comment: Hi Hugo,

I got it.There was a space in my CEWP after I removed that,it's working fine. Thanks A lot.

Comment: I have a problem now. If i put my mouse on one hyperlink I am getting description for every hyperlink. How to write jquery code in such a way that it only displays decription for the hovered hyperlink. Please help me and let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Can I control the speed of the hover? I mean Can i show the description slowly?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a tooltip plugin. [Jquery Tools overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) is a good one to do such tool tips. There are lot of other tool tip plugins available.